# JQuery JSDate addmonths errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add months to a date, and it adds the months properly because when i debugged it, it gave the proper date with months added, but when i try and convert it to a readable locale string it messes up the date. Anyone with any experience with jsDate can tell me what the problem is here? Or of any alternatives for this.

```
var d = new Date($('[id$=StartDate]').val());
var term = $('[id$=Term]').val();
d.addMonths(term);
$('[id$=EndDate]').val(Date.toLocaleDateString());
```

NOTE: Even using the jsdate function for `date.toString` caused errors in the text output.

Comment: jqPlot's jsDate and the JavaScript native `Date` functionality are quite different. If I'm right, your first issue is using the native functionality which doesn't have an `addMonths` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try to execute

```
d = d.addMonths(term);
```

, as I believe the `addMonths` is not modifying the state of the object, just calculates the d + term * month value, however, this is just a guess, as I have not used `jsDate` before.

Comment: yeah it isn't even exclusive to datejs the Javascript Date library is messed up completely.

Comment: If this answer helped you, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.